# Angular button icon not showing up

Tags: html, css, angular

Here is a screenshot of what is showing up on my webapp right now. It is supposed to be an add button, and the button functionality is there, but for some reason the image itself isn't showing up:

[image]

I am not sure if this would be an issue with what I am doing in my HTML or in my CSS, and have never really seen this problem before.

The HTML code relevant to this:

```
<button md-button class="add-btn" aria-label="add">
    <md-icon class="jf-add"></md-icon>
</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.add-btn {
    text-transform: none;
    color: #007ab4;

    > span {
        padding-left: 4px;
        vertical-align: sub;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side notes: 1)"jf-add" is a custom icon that is in my work's system 2) I am just an intern and new to CSS and HTML, so the problem could be a very simple fix

Comment: @Vega The icon is pre-defined, sorry that wasn't clear on my part

Comment: @Vega, I guess I must have worded myself incorrectly then, because elsewhere in the project there is a line of code that is similar to mine: `<md-icon class="jf-information">` which is just a different icon from the same library

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the material design in your module?

Example:

```
angular.module('buttons', ['ngMaterial'])
```

Also does not look like you defined the src of the icon in your button

Example:

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/cake.svg"></md-icon>
```

Comment: I do define the material design, yes